# Prevent elements behind from the overlay being clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### The issue

https://streamable.com/e/9z6lev (the flickering in the video is caused by the overlay being reopened every time meal plan is selected)

It "feels" like during the initial overlay open it's not the focused element and as result is's children can be clicked through :sad:

### Overlay Template

The logic for the overlay is quite simple, and allow to nest any type of content inside:

```
<template>
    <div class='swipeableWrapper'
         @click.stop.prevent // not original code, just attempt to fix the issue
         @touch.stop.prevent> // not original code, just attempt to fix the issue
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

.swipeableWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;

}
```

### Items List Template

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <ListProduct v-for='(product, index) in products'
            ...
            :showProduct='showProduct'
            :key='index' />
    </div>
<template>

// List Item
<template>
    <div class='listProduct'
         ... 
         @click='showProduct'>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

### Intended approaches:

1. The following logic added to the overlay template to prevent events from bubbling:

```
@click.stop.prevent 
@touch.stop.prevent
```

2. Global logic that will listen to opened overlay and add the following CSS class to the body element, in order to allow click on the overlay items, but still not much luck

```
.overlayOpened {
    & * {
        pointer-events: none;
        touch-action: none;
    }

    .swipeableWrapper {
        &,
        & * {
            pointer-events: auto;
            touch-action: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a bit puzzled with this dark magic behaviour and will really appreciate your opinion on the origin of the behaviour and possible solutions :bow:

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@click.self.prevent="function"
```

**Edited:**

For the list item and function as prop

```
:showProduct="() => showProduct(item/index)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've tried @click.self.prevent="() => {}" but it still misbehaves :-)

Comment: can you share your **v-for** and **@click function** of the menu item?

Comment: Did you pass item or index while calling related click function on item?

Comment: Just updated the question with `Items List Template`

Comment: After more tests, I really believe the problem is not with the list item itself, since I've tested overlay with other content and it's still clickable through until the user manually scrolls the content so that the focus get properly captured

Comment: `:showProduct="() => showProduct(item/index)`